# Cleaning bathtub toys that squirt water

Tags: toys, cleaning

What is the best way to clean out bath toys that store water?

Specifically, we have quite a few toys that have a hole in the bottom and can suck in water and squirt it out when squeezed. A few of those toys are next to impossible to empty of water completely and hence have started growing some mildew.

---

We're considering squirting vinegar (or possibly a diluted vinegar solution) into the toys and leaving them to stew for a while, but is there a Good Way of doing this? Naturally, any solution ought to be child-safe.

Comment: diluted bleach soak once in a while worked for us.

Comment: we have the same problem with the "bath ducks". Vinegar sounds good at first. However, I wonder  if the acid could attack the polymer and maybe set free a reaction product. Furthermore, acid is not child-safe IMHO and as you can not be sure to squeeze out all the water you'll have the same problem with the "detergent".

Comment: not really an answer, but I just throw them out once they start to either smell or look like they have mildew/mold. They tend to be really cheap.

Comment: I HATE those stupid things and my mother and mother-in-law INSIST on buying them!!!!

Comment: I have had the same problem. I wonder if using alcohol to sanitize them would work?

Comment: @woliveirajr How important are the "squeak" and or "squirt" functions?

Comment: Our solution is mostly to avoid buying that kind of toy (the plastic kinds that can get water up in them where you can't clean it), and when we do, we are fortunate that our oldest (almost 3) is a neat freak and has no problem tossing toys that are too grimy.  He mostly takes matchbox cars in the bath, which works well until they eventually rust presumably, but we have approximately 1,000,000 of them from various sources so that's not a big problem :)

Comment: One note, you might see if a latex/rubber duckie is more durable that way than a plastic one (or, the other way around, though I suspect latex/rubber is superior).

Comment: I just had to +1 for the fun nature of the question itself... "and his friends" hehe

Comment: @Jax for the mini-shower, squirt is a must-have, or we can't bath the ducks! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever possible, *throw them out*. You can't, unfortunately always do that (well you can, if you're ready for the consequences of being responsible for ducky's untimely demise).

I did this, which worked.

1. Submerge the toy in a 70% solution of rubbing alcohol. Squeeze it quite a few times
2. Repeat this process in hot (as you can tolerate) soapy water
3. Repeat again in hot (as you can tolerate) plain water.

When done, the toy should not smell like anything at all (well, aside from the smell of the latex / rubber).

Again, this works on something that isn't completely crusted inside with mold or mildew. When possible, just pitch the toy if it starts to reek. You can always do it on the sneak, after getting a replacement.

Answer (score 5):

To piggy-back just a bit on what Rory said, we regularly fill a sink with 4 parts water to 1 part bleach, drop the ducks in there, squeeze them a couple of times to fill them with the solution, and let them sit for a while (usually overnight). In the a.m., we empty the solution, squeeze the water out of them, fill the sink again with clean water, repeat the squeeze-to-fill routine, and let them sit for a while longer.  Then we empty the water from the basin, squeeze as much water out of the ducks as possible, and they can go back into the tub for playtime for another week or so.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was going to write, except, I would add that I sometimes seal bath toys that squeak and squirt (such as ducks) shut with silicone or superglue (depending on what I have handy) so that water can't get in there at all.

Answer (score 3):

We have three solutions to this, depending on the toy:

- If the toy is a must-have: A solution of Milton, or other mild sterilising solution
- If we can modify it a bit: drill more holes in it to get a proper cleaning flow through
- If it is unloved enough: ditch it

In saying that, though - most of our ducks are owned by the parents, not the kids (it started with me getting a signed Christopher Brookmyre duck...and I seem to keep getting celebrity ducks...)

Comment: What is Milton?  Is that bleach?

Comment: @JeremyMiller: I was about to ask "who is Milton", then I found this: http://www.milton-tm.com/en/consumer/faqs

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is not to buy bathtub toys that squirt water.

You can still have squirty fun. Just keep old shower jel bottles and use them instead. They hold a lot of water, and can be binned without worrying about cost.

Sooner or later, you will forget to clean your rubber duck, and it will fill with moldy sludge. This will both smell and be a health hazard. Its not worth it.

Comment: Your points are valid - but you are not answering the question. Mikey is asking _how do I_ and not _should I._ See [here](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/34/whats-the-best-strategy-to-combat-soapboxing) and [here](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/123/what-should-we-advise-when-one-disagrees-with-the-premise-of-a-question) on meta.

Comment: I would disagree. Had the person bought a single duck and wanted to know how to clean it, then I would have said "Wash it with TCP" or something along those lines. However, it is clear that they have bought a number of these toys. The best solution is not to buy the toys.

Comment: I've never bought a squirting duck, but my kids brought them home as prizes or gifts and so we have a moderate collection. Your answer doesn't really help at all.

Answer (score 1):

Some will clean in a steam sterilizer, but an oven at 60C is often the best treatment for such things. Then drop them in a sealed bag filled with white rice for 72h.

If you don't like chlorine bleach (e.g. Milton), Dapple and Pigeon cleansers both work well for just squeezing inside. You want to kill the mold asap.

Answer (score 1):

The dark thing inside are algae.  It is revolting and ends up making the water yucky.  I throw them away and replace them every month for two dollars at the dollar store, or throw in some McDonalds toys.  Very eco-unfriendly but I as a mom, I am an endangered species.  So are you.

Answer (score 0):

Bleach is a powerful biocide. I suggest you abandon your current algae prevention methods and instead just squirt a little diluted bleach (perhaps a couple of ml.) every few weeks  through the hole by which the water gets into the ducks, using a syringe. I can guarantee nothing will grow inside them if you do that.