# How to properly clean the ducks and his friends?

Tags: toys, cleaning, bathing

You know, [these ducks](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=rubber+duck&tbm=isch).

My little one loves her ducks, some ducks friends, a small manual portable shower, and so on: all they go to her bathtub and we play a lot.

In the end, although I squeeze, shake, dry using a hair-blower, there's always some water left inside. And no matter how I clean using hot water, put them in the boiling water on my stove, after some time I can notice that something (algae?) is developing inside. So I go and try everything again.

How can I clean them after every bath ? Or how can I clean them every x days?

*Edit*

Those cheaper ducks could be thrown away, but some of the others are hard to find/expensive. And the mini-shower wouldn't have any fun without splashing real water (that we use to bath the ducks during the bath).

For reference: an almost duplicate question but with different answers: [Cleaning bathtub toys that squirt water](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3599/cleaning-bathtub-toys-that-squirt-water?rq=1)